# PHP: sane way of checking POST data?

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

I have page1.php that uses a form to send the following data:

```
<form action="page2.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="f1">
<input type="text" name="f2">
<input type="text" name="f3">
<input type="text" name="f4">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

On page2.php, I do some basic validation so see that the form was actually submitted and that all data was entered:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != "POST" || empty($_POST["f1"]) || empty($_POST["f2"]) || empty($_POST["f3"]) || empty($_POST["f4"]))
{
    $missing_input = array();

    if (empty($_POST["f1"]))
    {
        $missing_input[] = "field1";
    }
    if (empty($_POST["f2"]))
    {
        $missing_input[] = "field2";
    }
    if (empty($_POST["f3"]))
    {
        $missing_input[] = "field3";
    }
    if (empty($_POST["f4"]))
    {
        $missing_input[] = "field4";
    }

    die("Error: " . implode(", ", $missing_input)");
}
?>
```

**The problem is that the above feels very ugly and needs re-work when a new POST field is introduced in the page1.php form. How can I code this form validation better?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store `f1`, `f2`, etc. in an array and use a for statement to iterate through the array.

Example:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != "POST")
    die("Error: Wrong method");
$fields = array("f1", "f2", "f3", "f4");
$field_names = array("field1", "field2", "field3", "field4");
$length = count($fields);
$missing_input = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
    if(empty($_POST[$fields[$i]]))
        $missing_input[] = $field_names[$i];
if(!empty($missing_input))
    die("Error: " . implode(", ", $missing_input)");
```

Note: The above is untested.

Comment: Yes, this did the trick. Just had to add an IF surrounding die(). Also, removed the request_method check per Col. Shrapnel suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

This works for any number of fields you put into your form

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != "POST") {
    die("Improper request method");
}

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $field) {
        if (strlen($field) === 0) {
            $missing_input[] = $key;
        }
    }
}   

if (!empty($missing_input)) {
    die("Error: " . implode(", ", $missing_input)");
}
```

Comment: Also, especially since you are checking if $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != "POST" you should make sure to use $_REQUEST instead of $_POST

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure what the "request method != post" is doing in his script.. if the request method is GET, the validation will fail anyway. But I added it at the top to be sure.

Comment: Suggest changing `if (!$field) {` to `if (strlen($field) === 0) {` to avoid colliding with falsy form post values.

Comment: @James True! No doubt anyone using this should do much sanitizing/escaping, it's just a structure template. I'll add it though, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple loop with a variable holding fieldnames :

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{
  $fieldnames = array(
    'f1' => 'field1',
    'f2' => 'field2'
    'f3' => 'field3'
    'f4' => 'field4'
  );
  $missing_input = $array();
  foreach ($fieldnames as $code => $label)
  {
    if (empty($_POST[$code]))
      {
          $missing_input[] = $label;
      }
  }

  //Display errors nicely
  if (count($missing_input) > 0):?>
  <p>The following fields are required :</p>
  <ul>
    <?php foreach ($missing_input as $field): ?>
    <li><?php echo $field ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
  <?php endif;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look at using a framework like zend or yii.  The short answer is that if you don't like doing it this way you would have to code up a class or object to do this.

Answer (score 0):

> above feels very ugly

That's wrong feeling.
If you need only check if field was empty, you can do some silly loop of course.

Bit in the real life there are different checks for the different fields, so, you have to write all them manually, in turn. There is nothing wrong with it.

the only issue I see here is redundant checks in the first line. why all these "|| empty" there?

Comment: With `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != "POST"` I'm trying to make sure that page2.php isn't directly accessed, i.e. that the user has submitted the form on page1.php. I use the various `empty($_POST["f1"])` so that the fields aren't left empty.

Comment: @BaUn don't you notice the you are checking it TWICE?

Comment: That's why I told it redundant. `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"` is enough.